# content pulled from a .doc file and displayed in a Tinymce editor

Tags: php

I want to display a .doc/.docx/.pdf/.txt file from a directory in the Tinymce Editor.
just like u see in monster(resume section)?
How can I achieve it?

Comment: The fourth one is easy. The first three ones are extremely complex, if not impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to convert the first three into HTML.
There exists some php projects that can do that. Try and google "php convert doc to HTML" and "php convert pdf to HTML" for example.
I use Linux applications though. They often give a much better result, but demands more of you. You can run the Linux applications with the [exec](http://php.net/exec) command, given that you work on Linux of course :)

If so, look at the applications pdf2html and jodconverter for doc files.